Issues loading a project with large non-local data in QGIS
I have some very large TIFFs from drone surveys that are on a Dropbox filing system. For anything to load in QGIS the file needs to be made available offline on Dropbox.
Some of my projects have these layers in, however they are now no longer available offline on Dropbox, as a result I am unable to open the projects that contain them. It is also not as easy as just making the data available offline, some of them are in excess of 80gb. When QGIS attempts to load the larger files it makes it constantly crash.
I'm curious if there is something within QGIS that you can do to make a project not attempt to load unavailable files? So you just load the layers panel, that way I could remove the non-local layers from the projects.

Is the file extension for your project .qgs or .qgz?

It's a .qgz file extension

Before you do any of this make sure you take a backup of your project file
As your file is a .qgz, first rename the file to change the extension to .zip. You can then extract the .qgs file from within.
Open the .qgs in a text editor and you'll see all of your project config. Look for the layers you want to remove, likely near the top of the file. Delete the 'layer-tree-layer' tag for all of the layers you want to remove, which will look similar to this (layer name 'Misc' in this example):
<layer-tree-layer patch_size="-1,-1" expanded="1" legend_split_behavior="0" legend_exp="" id="Misc_7e94cc4b_1ace_4cb8_92b6_d14ed01f738b" source="./Misc.tif" checked="Qt::Checked" name="Misc" providerKey="gdal">
  <customproperties>
    <Option/>
  </customproperties>
</layer-tree-layer>

Save the file and open the .qgs file in QGIS.
